# Почему ID не передает данные пользователя, которого редактируют?

Tags: php

profile.php

```
<?php include_once('include/config.php');?>
<?php include_once('include/function.php');?>
<?php
  if($_POST['button']){
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
  $tel = $_POST['tel'];
  $nomericq = $_POST['nomericq'];
  $skype = $_POST['skype'];
  $office = $_POST['office'];
  $otdel = $_POST['otdel'];
  $meid = $_GET['id'];
  //Обновляем данные
  $update = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET email = '$email', name = '$name', firstname = '$firstname',
                        tel = '$tel', nomericq = '$nomericq', skype = '$skype',
            office = '$office', otdel = '$otdel' WHERE id_user = '$meid'") or die (mysql_error());
  if($update){echo '<script>alert("Операция, успешно выполнена!");</script>';}
    echo "<script>history.go(-2)</script>";
}

?>
```

man.html

```
<a href="#x" class="overlay" id="edit_profile"></a>
        <div class="popup">
            <h2>Редактировать профиль</h2><br />
            <div>
    <form action="profile.php?id=<?=$row['id_user']; ?>"  method="POST" name="form" id="edit_profile">
                <label for="name">Имя:</label>
                <input name="name" class="input" type="text"  value="<?=$assoc['name'] ?>" maxlength="15"/>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="firstname">Фамилия:</label>
                <input name="firstname" class="input" type="text" value="<?=$assoc['firstname'] ?>" maxlength="25"/>
            </div>

      <div>
                <label for="email">Почтовый ящик:</label>
                <input name="email" class="input" type="text" value="<?=$assoc['email'] ?>" maxlength="25"/>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="tel">Телефон:</label>
                <input type="text" name="tel" value="<?=$assoc['tel'] ?>" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="nomericq">ICQ:</label>
                <input type="text" name="nomericq" value="<?=$assoc['nomericq'] ?>" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="skype">Skype:</label>
                <input type="text" name="skype" value="<?=$assoc['skype'] ?>" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="otdel">Отдел:</label>
                <select name="otdel" size="1">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>

    </select>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="office">Должность:</label>
                <select name="office" size="1">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>   
            </div>

            <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Отправить" name="button" class="button" onclick="return thisform(this.form)">
            <a href="#close" class="btn btn-danger">Отменить</a>
       </form>     
        </div>
<a href='#edit_profile'><img src="img/pencil.png" title="Редактировать"></a>
```

Comment: Вы создали искусственный интеллект? А обычно id передает? Данные сами редактируют? Вопрос ни о чем. И зачем в начале 3 раза "<?php"?
Man.html ахааха, простите)

Comment: Передает ID, под которым авториз-ся, т.е. я хочу отредактировать другой профиль, выходит форма редак-ия , но изменения применяются на авториз-ый ID, а который редактируешь нет.

Comment: Покажите полный код файла man.html , как заполняется и где, массив $row['id_user']; ?

Comment: onclick="return thisform(this.form)"   - а где код ? что там происходит то?

Comment: причем тут это...

Comment: при том, что у вас гдето переписывается `$row['uid']` на ваш авторизованный.

Comment: это то же самое что вам дадут код где использюются пользовательские функции, причем код функций не дадут, и спросят а че он у меня не работает то)) тут к сожалению телепатов нет - может правда в отпуске все

Comment: вот и я о том же))

Answer (score 1):

Эх вы.. Конечно не передает, кто же в form action суёт параметры запроса? Для этого есть скрытое поле формы.

```
<form action="profile.php?id=<?=$row['id_user']; ?>"  method="POST" name="form" id="edit_profile">
```

замените на

```
<form action="profile.php"  method="POST" name="form" id="edit_profile">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?=$row['id_user']; ?>">
```

Comment: с чего вдруг не передает?? все отлично передает.... почитайте rfc1866

Comment: а чебы и не засунуть, обычная передача параметров GET запросом)

Comment: ТС отправляет POST запрос. Да к тому же я по личному опыту знаю, что аттрибут action предназначен лишь для указания абсолютного или относительного адреса обработчика формы, а любые дописанные в action параметры теряются. <input type=hidden ...> не зря же создан)

Comment: параметры, засунутые в get запрос в action теряются если МЕТОД у формы action. в противном случае оно отлично передается туда. я к тому, что если личный не подразумевал использование таких конструкций, то это не значит что это нельзя делать :) я не говорю, что это правильно, прочитайте мой коммент к вопросу ТС ;)  

зыж я уж молчу, что параметры входящие никак не обрабатываются ;)

Comment: > параметры, засунутые в get запрос в action теряются если МЕТОД у формы action.
 
Поясните-ка это предложение :)
Если метод отправки данных из формы - POST, как в данном случае, то это нормально, что он (PHP-скрипт) не видит параметр id =)
Что же касается тех случев, когда метод отправки данных из формы - GET, то тогда, может быть, и отправится параметр, но опять же, имхо, это анальный способ..

Comment: да-да-да, если метод POST. в этом случае можно спокойно передавать в action'e GET запросы. я таким способом не побзуюсь, но гдето видел и это работает. почему в данном случае чтото происзходит не могу сказать. в любом случае просмотр запроса из браузера и `var_dump($_GET)` сможет много чего сказать. а лучше еще и к жтому запросу посмотреть `php_info()`  


ну если ваааще очень надо так, то я бы сделал (да и не только для этого) ЧПУ типа `/profile/5/`


зыж после 10часового раб дня все путается:)))

Comment: я не понимаю о чем мы спорим? проверьте же. вот [простая хрень](w.thunders.spb.ru/test.php)

вводите что хотите, после `submit`'a вывод `GET` и `POST`. Что и Где теряется? :)

Comment: Видимо, у меня был нестандартный случай. Но в той ситуации заработало только после переноса в скрытый `input`

Answer (score 0):

Так тег

```
<form
```

добавь.

И `get` и `post` не перемешивай.

`get` нужно в `form` добавить.
Но он может и не работать.

Comment: я уже по всякому пробовал, не работает